# GeoServer Application Schema GML output without geometry

Tags: geoserver, geometry, wfs, gml

I am working on an Application Schema example. The dataset is being built, the layer will be rendered as WMS, but the WFS-GML Output produces an empty tag where a Point geometry would be expected. 
I already reduced my complex schema to a rather simple one and spent days trying to find the cause. Observations will follow further down.

---

Here is my application schema:

````
<!--Generated by Enterprise Architect 13.5.1351 ( Build: 1351 )-->
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://geoserver.org/xe" version = "2.03"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xe="http://geoserver.org/xe"
xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">
    <!--xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="../../net/opengis/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gmlBase.xsd"/-->
    <xs:element name="XE_OrtVonInteresse" type="xe:XE_OrtVonInteresseType" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" abstract="true"></xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="XE_OrtVonInteresseType" abstract="true">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ovi_id" type="xs:integer"/>
                    <xs:element name="objektUUID" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="objektName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="lageanfasspunkt" type="gml:PointPropertyType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                    <!--<xs:element name="lageAnfasspunkt" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>-->             
                    <xs:element name="objektFunktion" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="XE_Aussichtspunkt" type="xe:XE_AussichtspunktType" substitutionGroup="xe:XE_OrtVonInteresse"></xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="XE_AussichtspunktType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xe:XE_OrtVonInteresseType">
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>```


----------

Here is my MappingFile

    ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <as:AppSchemaDataAccess xmlns:as="http://www.geotools.org/app-schema" xmlns:xe="http://geoserver.org/xe" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.geotools.org/app-schema AppSchemaDataAccess.xsd">
        <namespaces>
            <Namespace>
                <prefix>gml</prefix>
                <uri>http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2</uri>
            </Namespace>
            <Namespace>
                <prefix>xe</prefix>
                <uri>http://geoserver.org/xe</uri>
            </Namespace>
        </namespaces>
        <includedTypes> 
        </includedTypes>
        <sourceDataStores>
         <DataStore>
            <id>test_ds</id>
        <parameters>
            <Parameter>
                <name>dbtype</name>
                <value>postgisng</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>host</name>
                <value>localhost</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>port</name>
                <value>5432</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>database</name>
                <value>xe_db</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>user</name>
                <value>ca</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>passwd</name>
                <value>clandrae</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>schema</name>
                <value>xe_gs</value>
            </Parameter>
            <Parameter>
                <name>Expose primary keys</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </Parameter>
        </parameters>
        </DataStore>
        </sourceDataStores>
        <!--<catalog>catalog.xml</catalog>-->
        <targetTypes>
            <FeatureType>
                 <schemaUri>test.xsd</schemaUri>
            </FeatureType>
        </targetTypes>
        <typeMappings>
          <FeatureTypeMapping>
                <sourceDataStore>test_ds</sourceDataStore>
                <sourceType>test2</sourceType>
                <targetElement>xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt</targetElement>
                <defaultGeometry>xe:lageanfasspunkt</defaultGeometry>
                <attributeMappings>
                      <AttributeMapping>
                        <targetAttribute>xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt</targetAttribute>
                        <idExpression><OCQL>ovi_code_id</OCQL></idExpression>
                    </AttributeMapping>
                     <AttributeMapping>
                        <targetAttribute>xe:ovi_id</targetAttribute>
                        <sourceExpression><inputAttribute>ovi_id</inputAttribute></sourceExpression>
                    </AttributeMapping>
                    <AttributeMapping>
                        <targetAttribute>xe:lageanfasspunkt</targetAttribute>
                        <targetAttributeNode>gml:PointPropertyType</targetAttributeNode>
                        <sourceExpression><OCQL>lageanfasspunkt</OCQL></sourceExpression>
                        <idExpression><OCQL>strConcat('point_',ovi_code_id)</OCQL></idExpression>
                    </AttributeMapping>
                    <AttributeMapping>
                        <targetAttribute>xe:objektUUID</targetAttribute>
                        <sourceExpression><inputAttribute>objektuuid</inputAttribute></sourceExpression>
                    </AttributeMapping>
                      <AttributeMapping>
                        <targetAttribute>xe:objektName</targetAttribute>
                        <sourceExpression><inputAttribute>objektname</inputAttribute></sourceExpression>
                    </AttributeMapping>
                     <AttributeMapping>
                        <targetAttribute>xe:objektFunktion</targetAttribute>
                        <sourceExpression><inputAttribute>objektfunktion</inputAttribute></sourceExpression>
                    </AttributeMapping>
                    </attributeMappings>
            </FeatureTypeMapping>
        </typeMappings>
    </as:AppSchemaDataAccess>
````

---

And here is my PostGIS table:

```
        ovi_id integer,
        ovi_code_id text,
        objektname text NOT NULL,
        objektuuid text,
        objektfunktion text,
        lageanfasspunkt public.geometry(Point,25832) NOT NULL
    );

    ALTER TABLE xe_gs.test2 OWNER TO ca;

    INSERT INTO xe_gs.test2 VALUES (373, '2384', 'Sternwarte auf dem Galgenberg', '46873230-b825-e8aa-4c57-1d7ed0750964', 'Aussichtspunkt', '0101000020E8640000BECF5188FAE91841A1FEBC2589D05541');
    INSERT INTO xe_gs.test2 VALUES (1214, '2385', 'Varnhöveler Warte', 'e80dc111-ffb3-9e35-504c-9a587946f96a', 'Aussichtspunkt', '0101000020E8640000C15D2E3EB08118413A8184D66FD55541');
    INSERT INTO xe_gs.test2 VALUES (19, '1194', 'Galgenberg', 'b3524707-b8b3-a439-6bf8-d489f2e7f4e5', 'Aussichtspunkt', '0101000020E864000059A308D3C8E8184152A7E01172D05541');
    INSERT INTO xe_gs.test2 VALUES (2552, '1207', 'Adener Höhe', '69c611b8-93b3-efbd-febe-be53f9c55ccc', 'Aussichtspunkt', '0101000020E86400007B176FCD14A918414FCC35AAF1D15541');
    INSERT INTO xe_gs.test2 VALUES (159, '1238', 'Test-Punkt', '31ffccc9-2878-6bf2-d228-1f2a3c40d5d6', 'Aussichtspunkt', '0101000020E86400000000000090DE18410000004077CE5541');
    INSERT INTO xe_gs.test2 VALUES (88, '2314', 'Zeche Monopol', '0f646068-9a93-c9d7-3f4f-d39a7f0fdb75', 'Aussichtspunkt', '0101000020E86400005EF0715D3CCD184152DBE97449CE5541');
```

---

And this is the GML Output:

`<lageanfasspunkt>` is supposed to contain a POINT geometry.
The logging does not show any errors. The geometry is interpreted correctly.
WMS rendering is possible. However, the element lageanfasspunkt remains empty.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:FeatureCollection xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xe="http://geoserver.org/xe" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" numberMatched="unknown" numberReturned="6" timeStamp="2020-03-22T12:58:04.801Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/2.0/wfs.xsd http://geoserver.org/xe file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/geoserver-2.16.2/data_dir/data/xe/test.xsd http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2 http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd"><wfs:member>
<xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt gml:id="1194">
<xe:ovi_id>19</xe:ovi_id>
<xe:objektUUID>b3524707-b8b3-a439-6bf8-d489f2e7f4e5</xe:objektUUID>
<xe:objektName>Galgenberg</xe:objektName>
<xe:lageanfasspunkt/>
<xe:objektFunktion>Aussichtspunkt</xe:objektFunktion></xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt></wfs:member><wfs:member>
<xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt gml:id="1207">
<xe:ovi_id>2552</xe:ovi_id>
<xe:objektUUID>69c611b8-93b3-efbd-febe-be53f9c55ccc</xe:objektUUID>
<xe:objektName>Adener Höhe</xe:objektName>
<xe:lageanfasspunkt/>
<xe:objektFunktion>Aussichtspunkt</xe:objektFunktion></xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt></wfs:member><wfs:member>
<xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt gml:id="1238">
<xe:ovi_id>159</xe:ovi_id>
<xe:objektUUID>31ffccc9-2878-6bf2-d228-1f2a3c40d5d6</xe:objektUUID>
<xe:objektName>Test-Punkt</xe:objektName>
<xe:lageanfasspunkt/>
<xe:objektFunktion>Aussichtspunkt</xe:objektFunktion></xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt></wfs:member><wfs:member>
<xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt gml:id="2314">
<xe:ovi_id>88</xe:ovi_id>
<xe:objektUUID>0f646068-9a93-c9d7-3f4f-d39a7f0fdb75</xe:objektUUID>
<xe:objektName>Zeche Monopol</xe:objektName>
<xe:lageanfasspunkt/>
<xe:objektFunktion>Aussichtspunkt</xe:objektFunktion></xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt></wfs:member><wfs:member>
<xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt gml:id="2384">
<xe:ovi_id>373</xe:ovi_id>
<xe:objektUUID>46873230-b825-e8aa-4c57-1d7ed0750964</xe:objektUUID>
<xe:objektName>Sternwarte auf dem Galgenberg</xe:objektName>
<xe:lageanfasspunkt/>
<xe:objektFunktion>Aussichtspunkt</xe:objektFunktion></xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt></wfs:member><wfs:member>
<xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt gml:id="2385">
<xe:ovi_id>1214</xe:ovi_id>
<xe:objektUUID>e80dc111-ffb3-9e35-504c-9a587946f96a</xe:objektUUID>
<xe:objektName>Varnhöveler Warte</xe:objektName>
<xe:lageanfasspunkt/>
<xe:objektFunktion>Aussichtspunkt</xe:objektFunktion></xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt></wfs:member></wfs:FeatureCollection>
```

What did I try so far?

```
- Switch to GeoSever 2.16 from version 2.14. 
- PostGIS table with/without OIDs
- PostGIS table and xsd-Schema with type Geometry vs type Point
- Use SRID 4326 instead of 25832
- Use View instead of table
- Control geometry_columns; this is an automatically updated view and contains my table/view-Information.
- Control Namespace declarations and add a Secondary Namespace-Declaration for GML.
- Try mapping File with and without default_geometry declaration.
- Try lowercase field names instead of lowerCamelCase. 
- Try renaming 'lageanfasspunkt' to 'the_geom'.
- Try different GML versions. GML2.0 doesnt work due to schema incompatibility.
- GML-Output format 3.1 makes no difference to 3.2.
- Try WFS GET vs Post
- Try GML-Namespace-Declaration in WFS-POST-Request
- Try using various WFS-Requests like

    http://localhost:8080/geoserver/xe/wfs?service?WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=xe:XE_Aussichtspunkt&format=application/gml+xml;version=3.2
```

---

### Observations:

- WMS works with default Style point.
- Defining an own style results in
  GeoServer not finding the geometry, also when explicitly defined in
  the symbolizer.
- GeoJSON Output possible with correct Point definition
  (>> GeoServer is able to build the points!).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I got a response via the geoserver email forum with a suggestion for the xsd schema. The import of gml-namespace must not be deactivated. 
So here is the working schema:

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://geoserver.org/xe" version = "2.03"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xe="http://geoserver.org/xe"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2">;
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" schemaLocation="http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1/gml.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="XE_OrtVonInteresse" type="xe:XE_OrtVonInteresseType" substitutionGroup="gml:AbstractFeature" />
    <xs:complexType name="XE_OrtVonInteresseType" abstract="true">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ovi_id" type="xs:integer"/>
                    <xs:element name="objektUUID" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="objektName" type="xs:string"/>
                    <xs:element name="lageanfasspunkt" type="gml:GeometryPropertyType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>         
                    <xs:element name="objektFunktion" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="XE_Aussichtspunkt" type="xe:XE_AussichtspunktType" substitutionGroup="xe:XE_OrtVonInteresse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="XE_AussichtspunktType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xe:XE_OrtVonInteresseType">
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This solved the problem.